# How to open a multiple message box with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a multiple chatbox messaging like Facebook's popup messenger windows. At the moment, the user can call up a chatbox, close it, minimize it, etc.

When I click on multiple users, say 3, I'm supposed to have three chatboxes pop up corresponding to those three different users. Currently, only one chatbox appears.

This screenshot illustrates what I want to achieve. On each user's button click, it's own chatbox will popup.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the demo and download link for a jQuery equivalent: [link](https://skptricks.github.io/learncoding/facebook%20like%20chat%20application%20example/Chat-Application.html).

This is the full React code which shows just one chat box:

```jsx
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import './style.css';

class MessageBox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showBox: false,
      shownToggle: true,
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "Tony" },
        { id: "2", name: "Mark" },
        { id: "3", name: "Joy" }
      ],
      currentRec: undefined,
    };

    this.showBox = this.showBox.bind(this);
    this.closeBox = this.closeBox.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  showBox = (i, pid, name) => {
    this.setState({ currentRec: i });
    console.log(`Selected record index: ${i}`);

    alert(pid);
    alert(name);

    this.setState({ showBox: true }, () => {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
    });
  }

  closeBox(event) {
    if (this.dropdownBox.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({ showBox: false }, () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
      });
    }
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      shownToggle: !this.state.shownToggle
    });
  }

  render() {
    var hidden = {
      display: this.state.shownToggle ? "block" : "none"
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ul style={{ float: "right" }}>
          {this.state.data.map((person, i) => (
            <div className="chat-sidebar" key={i}>
              <button onClick={() => this.showBox(i, person.id, person.name)}>Chat with {person.name}</button>
              {this.state.showBox ? (
                <div className="msg_box" style={{ right: '270px' }}>
                  <div onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} class="msg_head">
                    (<b style={{ color: 'orange' }}>
                      {this.state.currentRec !== undefined &&
                        <div className="modal-body">
                          {this.state.data[this.state.currentRec].name}
                          ({this.state.data[this.state.currentRec].id})
                        </div>
                      }
                    </b>)
                    Minimize
                    <div className="close" ref={(element) => { this.dropdownBox = element; }} style={{ color: 'white' }}>Close</div>
                  </div>
                  <div style={hidden} className="msg_wrap"><div className="msg_body">Message will appear here</div></div>
              </div>) : (null)}
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```css
/****** Chat Popup Layout ******/
body{
  background: #e5e5e5;  
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.msg_box{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 250px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.msg_head{  
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.msg_body{
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.close{
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.minimize{
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

/****** Slider Layout Popup ******/
.chat-sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After series of efforts, the use of jquery  and Reactjs is what solved my issue as per code below

```
const dataSet = this.state.data;
alert(dataSet);
  if ($.inArray(pid, dataSet) != -1)
   {
dataSet.splice($.inArray(pid, this.state.data), 1);

    }
    dataSet.unshift(pid);
      var s = 270 ; // start position
    var j = 260;  //next position

    $.each(dataSet, function( index, value ) {  
       if(index < 4){
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').css("right",s);
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();

         s = s+j;   

       }
       else{
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').hide();
       }
```